# How to triple join tables to find and find entries that match two things?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a simple problem that's hard to describe (at least for me).

Consider the following schema for a database modeling courses:

COURSE (cid, did, name, num, creditHours),

STUDENT (sid, fname, lname, did)

ENROLLED_IN (eid, sid, cid)

**What is a query that will find the sid of the students enrolled in course.name=Math" and "Science"?**

I'm sorry i asked a similar (simpler) question thinking I could figure the rest out but I could not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902489/how-to-find-entries-in-database-that-meet-multiple-matches

Comment: I misread this initially.  Are you looking for the sid of those students who are enrolled in both Math and Science?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS the other page suggests, you need to do two JOIN's to the same table.  But since you want to use the Name and not the cid, you join to the COURSE based on the enrollment data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.sid
FROM STUDENT s
INNER JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON e.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.cid = e.cid AND c.Name = 'Math'
INNER JOIN COURSE c2 ON c2.cid = e.cid AND c2.Name = 'Science'
```

If you need the whole student record, then...

```
SELECT STUDENT.*
FROM STUDENT
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT s.sid
   FROM STUDENT s
   INNER JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON e.sid = s.sid
   INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.cid = e.cid AND c.Name = 'Math'
   INNER JOIN COURSE c2 ON c2.cid = e.cid AND c2.Name = 'Science'
) t0 ON t0.sid = STUDENT.sid
```

EDIT Instead of DISTINCT you could also use GROUP BY, ala

```
   SELECT s.sid
   FROM STUDENT s
   INNER JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON e.sid = s.sid
   INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.cid = e.cid AND c.Name = 'Math'
   INNER JOIN COURSE c2 ON c2.cid = e.cid AND c2.Name = 'Science'
   GROUP BY s.sid
```

EDIT and instead of using two joins, you can use `HAVING` clauses

```
SELECT s.sid
FROM STUDENT s
INNER JOIN ENROLLED_IN e ON e.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN COURSE c ON c.cid = e.cid
WHERE c.Name IN ('Math', 'Science')
GROUP BY s.sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Hmm this is not working. After you add the last join for science, it returns blank result

Comment: It says ambigous column name 'c.cid'

Comment: Yea that second join should be `c2`... my bad.  I fixed my post.  But also see my edit about a `HAVING` clause.